# JSON.Net - Deserialize into a class which has Inheritance

Tags: c#, json, compact-framework, json.net

With JSON.Net, how do I get the Deserialization process to ignore a field that's inherited from a parent class (which I do not have access to).

I have a field in my JSON feed which matches the same name as one inherited from a system class. And when it tries to deserialize, it fails because of this (with the exact error message:

```
A member with the name 'Location' already exists on 'Client.JSON.MyClass'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.
```

The Location is defined in the parent class which is also a system class, and so I do not have access to that class in order to define a JsonIgnore attribute.

How do I bypass this so my deserialization can occur without attempting to deserialize the JSON Location property into the system class which MyClass inherits from?

A final note, the JSON feed is generated using WCF Data Services, and so contains the 'd' root array - I was informed about the ContractResolver but I could not get this to work because of the 'd' array (using the following code):

```or-tag-here
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Client.JSON
{
    public class MyClassContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(JsonObjectContract t)
        {
            IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(t);

            properties =
                properties.Where(p => p.PropertyName.StartsWith('J'.ToString())).ToList();

            return properties;
        }
    }
}
```

And deserializing using the following code:

```or-tag-here
jsonAppointments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootMyClass>(myJsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new MyClassContractResolver() });
```

If someone knows how to do this, it would be much appreciated! Thanks. This is using Compact Framework by the way.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your JSON and also show your class definition?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem. I solved it by hiding the base property, but without changing its behavior.

Assuming that `Location` is of type `string`:

```
class MyClass : RootMyClass
{
    [JsonIgnore] public new string Location
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Location;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Location = value;
        }
    }
}
```